# Setting a JFrame without overlapping with taskbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I need to have a undecorated JFrame(***setUndecorated(true)***) which need to be shown fullscreen, without overlapping with the taskbar.

I have tried the below solutions.

- Calling setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH).

  - **Advantage**: 
    This works fine as expected, i.e., the window is getting adjusted itself dynamically, except it has the below issues.
  - **Issues**
    Initially the window occupies the fullscreen
    Though the frame get adjusted itself dynamically, it overlaps with the taskbar.
- Tried the below solution as stated in [Does JFrame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH) work with undecorated frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403584/does-jframe-setextendedstatemaximized-both-work-with-undecorated-frames)

  ```
   GraphicsConfiguration config = aFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
   Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
   aFrame.setBounds(0, 0, usableBounds.width, usableBounds.height);
  ```

  - **Advantage**: 
    I am not getting overlaps and window looks fine.
  - **Issue**: 
    Window is not adjusting itself dynamically when the taskbar position/size is changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I thought of a design. But not sure about its feasibility. I can use the setBounds(). But then I need my frame to be notified when the task bar is adjusted or repositioned. Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to achieve this, at least without going to a native level

Comment: @MadProgrammer NO You can do that with GraphicsEnvironment class. Check my solution

Comment: @Thuiya NO it doesn't automatically update when the task bar is changed

Comment: @MadProgrammer we can have thread to check whether screen size get changed.

Comment: @Thuiya You could attach a native callback that would so the same result without the overhead of a Thread, but that's just my opinion

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes. I Think that would be a good option.

Comment: I'm confused that you want to do something that's literally the *exact opposite* of your previous question, or am I missing something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606700/to-have-a-jframe-without-adjusting-for-taskbar-change

Comment: Note that although Windows always covers the taskbar when an undecorated window is maximized, I think other OSes don't.

Comment: @Boann: Dont relate this with the previous question. I was just experimenting for my previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Able to able to fix the above issue with the below code,

```
Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
setMaximizedBounds(usableBounds);
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

So by  `getUsableBounds` I am able to get the bounds leaving the taskbar. And hence I am using `setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` the window is getting updated automatically when I re-size/re-position the taskbar. :-)

Comment: It was not working for me on few system, the problem was on window 10, the display setting of scale and layout was set to 125%, by changing it to 100% it start working. tested on JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Point x = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();
```

Have a separate thread to check whether taskbar get changed. If so update size

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        if (x.equals(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint())) {
           Rectangle r = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
           setSize(r.getSize());
        }
        try {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     }
  }).start();
```

Comment: setSize() didn't work. The behavior same as i mentioned for setBounds(). The window size is not getting updated dynamically when I change the size/position of the taskbar.

Comment: Are you suggesting to have a thread that runs indefinitely and updates the size of the frame based on the taskbar?