# How can I prevent a Jframe from overlapping with taskbar in Windows 8.1?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, taskbar

I need a Jframe to be set as fullscreen on startup, but when I do so, it overlaps with taskbar.

I watched this post:

[Setting a JFrame without overlapping with taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632093/setting-a-jframe-without-overlapping-with-taskbar)

But I am still not able to have the Jframe fullsize not overlapping taskbar on Windows 8.1.

The constructor of my main Jframe looks like this:

```
public Principal(Conexion c) throws SQLException {
    initComponents();
    GraphicsConfiguration config = getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
    setMaximizedBounds(usableBounds);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Removed Netbeans tag, since you'd do it exactly the same way in Eclipse (i.e. 'write Java code').

Comment: Start by dropping the `setMaximizedBounds`

Comment: Had a quick play on Windows 7 and using `setMaximizedBounds` and `setExtendedState` do freaky things. Personally, I'd avoid it (`setMaximizedBounds`)

Answer (score 0):

see follow code may help you

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

}
```

if you use netbeans then tick true on Resizable